# Show and hide selected columns with single macro in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Starting out like all others. I am new to macros and I know what I'm trying to do is easy, but I can't get it working.

So I'm making buttons on a spreadsheet to show and hide columns, if the column is hidden then show, if the column is shown then hide. So a toggle button between show and hide basically.

I will continue to research while this is here as I'm sure the answer is simple. Just an If, then, else but I'm a noob.

Any help would be appreciated. Here's one of the 'show' ones I have if it's easier to edit that.

Thanks

```
function ShowCA() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().showColumns(6);

};
```

Comment: This is in google sheets. Forgot to mention that

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- About the column "F", when the column is showing, you want to hide the column. When the column is hiding, you want to show the column.
- You want to achieve this using a function of Google Apps Script.

In this case, I thought that `isColumnHiddenByUser` can be used. So, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function ShowCA() {
  var column = 6; // This is column "F".

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  if (sheet.isColumnHiddenByUser(column)) {
    sheet.showColumns(column);
  } else {
    sheet.hideColumns(column);
  }
}
```

- When this script is run, when the column "F" is showing, the column is hidden. When the column "F" is hiding, the column is shown.

#### References:

- [isColumnHiddenByUser(columnPosition)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#iscolumnhiddenbyusercolumnposition)
- [showColumns(columnIndex)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#showcolumnscolumnindex)
- [hideColumns(columnIndex)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hidecolumnscolumnindex)